# How can I list all WordPress users, their email adress, post title and post status?

Tags: list-authors

I am looking for a way to return something like the following:

- User, email, post title, post status
- User, email, post title, post status
- repeated....

Each user on my site has only 1 post.  It is a custom post type called Company Listing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with a simple loop assuming that the users are also the authors of the post,
create a template page, and copy the inside of your page.php to it.

then replace the loop part with this code:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'company-listing', //change this to your actual CPT name
    'posts_per_page' => -1, //-1 to get all or any number you want to use with pagination
);
query_posts($args);
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
User, email, post title, post status
    <div class="post company-listing">
    <ul>
<?php  $user_info = get_userdata($post->post_author); ?>
        <li class="user">
            <?php echo $user_info->user_nicename; ?>
        </li>
        <li class="email">
            <?php echo $user_info->user_email; ?>
        </li>
        <li class="title">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </li>
        <li class="status">
            <?php echo $post->post_status; ?>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>

<?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php else: ?>

        <p class="no-data">
            <?php _e('Sorry, no page matched your criteria.'); ?>
        </p><!-- .no-data -->
 <?php endif; ?>
```

and add this little code css to style it right:

```
<style type="text/css">
company-listing ul li{ float: left;padding: 2px;}
</style>
```

now you didn't specify what is "USER" so i just showed you how to use user_nicename but after this line `$user_info = get_userdata($post->post_author);` you can use $user_info with:

- user_firstname
- user_lastname
- ID
- user_login
- user_pass
- user_nicename
- user_email
- user_url
- user_registered
- display_name

and a few more.

As  for status i assume you are talking about the post_status so you will need to add `'post_status' => array('publish','pending','draft','future','private',....)` to your $args.

and if you are talking about a custom filed then just call that field with `get_post_meta($post->ID,'status_field_name',true);`

Hope this helps

Comment: If limit the number of posts and use pagination, the same post load on each page.  Is there something here that is making that happen?

Comment: yeah you would need to add `$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;` and then to your `$args` array `'paged' => $paged;`

Comment: Glad i could help